# Can we do chart installation in tiller instead of helm client?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

In current Helm architecture, charts are downloaded by helm client and then sent to tiller to render the template and eventually, deploy those on kubernetes cluster.

I was wondering if there is any specific architectural benefit of handling chart installation part in client instead of tiller server.
Maybe that way we can have caching of charts at a common place too.

Comment: You might find reading through https://github.com/helm/community/blob/master/helm-v3/000-helm-v3.md informative: the proposal is to get rid of Tiller in Helm v3.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze ! This was super helpful. I was just thinking about some of the benefits which the earlier design provided v/s the proposed one.